# How to change page title for admin users to easly find which admin page they are

Tags: 7

During development I need to work with modules, views, site configurations, nodes etc.. I open all of them in new tabs (browser). It would be much convenient to switch between tabs to choose desired page if page title (**html title that displays in the browser)** has name of the admin navigation link/name. I have set 'Seven' as admin theme. Is there any configuration available to enable this or I need to tweek code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shortcut bar](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/shortcut),

> The Shortcut module provides a toolbar on the top of the page to which
>   you can add links. This toolbar is site-wide, so any links added will
>   be visible to all users who have permissions to see the Shortcut
>   toolbar. This is useful for creating links to commonly-used pages
>   within your site. You can organize these links in multiple sets of
>   shortcuts.

Click on the + sign as shown below in any page you want to bookmark

[image]

You will see links next to Add Content , Find Content like below

[image]

Explained in link given above...

Comment: I am using this module already. Where can I find the configuration settings to display the admin section in the title bar? May be my question was not clear. I have updated it

Comment: You cannot modify the title bar text with the shortcut module.

Answer (score 0):

By default with drupal the title should be [page-title] | [site-name].
If yours are not then it is possible that your theme or a module is changing your page titles.

For enhanced page title configuration there is also the [page title](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) module.

It allows you to set the page titles for nodes, users, etc.

It doesn't specifically have settings for admin pages, however it has a default page title, which will affect admin pages.

So you can enable that module and configure the default to whatever suits you best.